# Do devices on the LAN side and WAN side of a router adjust to a slow connection?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

I use a Wireless ISP in a rural area and am curious why some incoming or outgoing traffic overloads my Internet connection.

For example, if my iPhone has Background Refresh enabled it causes a heartbeat-like burst of 4-digit latency that lasts several seconds, basically killing my wireless link during that 10-sec burst. My Google Nest Hub causes the same problem when it fetches a new picture every minute. OneDrive can saturate my connection during syncing.

I ran some tests using an iPerf-like program, CST, between my site and a site in town that has a 100Mbps fiber connection to my WISP. Any traffic greater than 12 down and 2 up saturates my wireless link.

By request my WISP set a bandwidth cap of 12 down and 2 up in their Cambium SM at my place. (I would have preferred that they cap my download rate at their nearby AP -- with 1 Gb backhaul -- because I believe the weak spot is the link between their AP and SM.)

I am still suffering from frequent short periods (5 to 10 sec) of 3- and 4-digit latency, and lost packets. This has a lot of impact when working via GotomyPC and making voip calls.

With the above description as the context, what is expected to happen when a device or server sends data from a fast Internet connection to a slow connection?

How about a device on my LAN, is it made aware of the limits of my connection's upload capacity?

Answer (score 0):

> I use a Wireless ISP in a rural area and am curious why some incoming or outgoing traffic overloads my Internet connection.

Read up on [bufferbloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat).

> what is expected to happen when a device or server sends data from a fast Internet connection to a slow connection?

The internet procotols (e.g. TCP) normally adjust to the slowest part of the chain by changing transmit speed based on how packets are dropped.

With excessive (for the slow connection) buffers along the path, this never happens at the sender, so you got massive retransmission requests, which slow down things even further.

> How about a device on my LAN

It's the same in the other direction, but as the sender encounters the bottleneck before lots of buffering takes place, your local sender usually adjusts it's speed correctly. Unless the connection is already swamped by other devices using it, then all bets are off.

Comment: Thank you for the insights, @dirkt.  Does the sawtooth pattern in the following screencaps of PingLogger results indicate bufferbloat?  https://i.imgur.com/yBjGXkS.png  https://i.imgur.com/mi1c9Si.png

Comment: It definitely shows something recovering from initial big latency, which is consistent with "sender sends lots of data which get buffered, so it takes time until packages get dropeed, so it takes some time until sender throttles, and sender needs several iterations to do so". It's difficult to say anything definite if one can only measure at your end.